# Background task with progress tracking without Celery or Redis

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, python-multithreading

My project do some export from one to another service. For do it, need a long background task and show progress as some text like `current step` of progress. One problem is how to get this text from long task.

I know about `Celery` and `Redis`. But it is needed additional resource like server. The my project is too small and does not count on attendance of more than a couple of people once a month. So I don't want to buy a shared hosting or a machine.

I tried to save this `current step text` into `session`. But response during `long task` is always `null`. I think because `flask` is busy with the task and does not return a valid value for the `session`. Tried to run the task in a new thread. Then I get an error about accessing the session from the wrong thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My solution

Create global dict

```
step = dict()
```

Create random `key` and give this key with global step into module a background task. Start a new thread and return key.

```
@app.route('/api/transfer', methods=['post'])
def api_transfer():
    global step
    key = token_urlsafe(10)

    service = Service(step, key, session.get('token'))

    t = threading.Thread(target=long_task, args=(service,))
    t.start()

    return {'key': key}
```

And send request with this key to get response current step for it

```
@app.route('/api/transfer/current_step', methods=['post'])
def api_current_step():
    global step
    return {'step': step[request.json['key']]}
```

Now for every request to export will create new key and text for only it

```
{'jlIG7VKtbMHtXg': 'some step for jlIG7VKtbMHtXg'}
{'jlIG7VKtbMHtXg': 'some step for jlIG7VKtbMHtXg', 'wxr4jKyP7c72sg': 'some step for wxr4jKyP7c72sg'}
```

And at the end of the task, remove this key from the dictionary

```
del self.step[self.key]
```